# JavaScript Code Works Faster when JS Profiling is on? What?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm facing a very strange behaviour with my application - if I start the profiler (must be JS profiler), the code works almost twice as fast.

I've reproduced it with a very simple code which can be found on this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zagrwk44/

The thing is that this reproduces only on machines with old graphic cards. I've managed to reproduce it on a machine with **AMD Radeon HD 6450** graphic card. On a newer machine this does not reproduce anymore.

How come the profiler makes the code run faster?? almost **twice as fast**!

The code that takes the time here is just changing the position of a div on the screen:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    box.style.top = getRandomInt(0, 100) + '%';
    box.style.left = getRandomInt(0, 100) + '%';                
};
```

I'm starting and stopping the profiler via javascript with `console.profile` and `console.profileEnd`. **In order to reproduce it, DevTools must be opened when running.**

Thanks!

Comment: Here is another case where having profiling enabled can dramatically improve performance (along with fix): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60573388/react-app-slows-to-a-crawl-with-chrome-developer-tools-open-works-fine-in-incog

Answer (score 11):

Can't repro on my machine. 
But I'm curious do you compare a run with DevTools open vs a run with profiler? If so, the explanation could be that DevTools disables internal notifications, like updates to the Elements panel when profiling is active.
If you're comparing a run with DevTools closed, then it really looks strange.

Comment: For anyone who has the same mysterious issue, this is exactly what was the problem for me. DevTools was slowing things down by about 10x. But if I ran the same commands with devtools closed, then things were just fine. Tipoff was that other browsers weren't having the same slowdown and profiler was removing the slowdown.

Answer (score 8):

I experienced the same issue and I can reproduce this on any machine.

DevTools itself is slowing down your code execution, and this only affects JS code that modifies the DOM. This issue doesn't affect JS code that doesn't touch the DOM.

If you look at the "Elements" tab in DevTools while rapidly modifying the DOM, it flickers and highlights modified elements every time an HTML element is modified. I further confirmed this by testing on SVG charts with tons of elements.

The Chrome profiler clearly disables this DOM-modification visualization feature when it is on. In other words, the speed of the profiler should be the same as the speed when DevTools is closed.

So, sadly, I have to close DevTools to keep playing with my big SVG charts.

Comment: Is there a way to tell DevTools to disable whatever it disables during the Profiler?
also having this issue - it is annoying opening/closing DevTools for the expensive operations it hangs on; it would be nicer to just keep it open and enable/disable this expensive DOM specific feature it uses.  One workaround is to constantly keep the profiler active but thats not ideal either since sometimes you will need to inspect the DOM Source / Elements tab but you can't with Profiler running.

Comment: That sounds like a nice feature. And it seems like it could be solved by polling the DOM tree instead of continually updating it. You should raise this issue with the Chromium/Chrome devs. Maybe there are browsers other than Chrome that already do this? I'm not sure.

Comment: At first when I read this, I thought no way this is true. Tried it and it is actually the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I found this strange behavior which only happen to me on "Windows server 2008 R2 enterprise" OS.

your tester is not correct indication since it test the performance with a random function which could lead to a different results for every sample, more than that you are not exclude the **console.profile()** and **console.profileEnd()** from the time sampling which mean you never got a real native results.

To get a better and realistic result the code should look like this:

```
var random = [80,90,15,5,70,50,60,25,36,45,62,58,76,23,93];

fbtn.addEventListener('click', function() {

    //START PROFILE BEFOR TIME START
    if (withProfiling.checked) {
      console.profile();
    }

    console.time('click handler'); 
    for (var i = 0, v =0; i < 1000000; i++, v++) {
      box.style.top = random[v] + '%'; //USE SAME NUMBERS FOR ALL TESTS
      box.style.left = random[v] + '%';//USE SAME NUMBERS FOR ALL TESTS 

      if(v >= 14){
        v= 0;
      }         
    };
    console.timeEnd('click handler');

    // STOP PROFILE AFTER TIME END
    if (withProfiling.checked) {
           console.profileEnd();
        }
   });
```

here is a tester which could trace it in more depth:
http://embed.plnkr.co/bdreL4UVFyyWtDoNTXRs/

i remove the starting profiler by code, cause i found this strange behavior restore better by starting the profiles manualy.

to restore it select the  "Collect Javascript CPU Profile" from the profiles from DevTools on Chrome.

Hope it was useful,

Menachem